# Question about proof on commutative algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I deleted my previous post in order to make a more specific one. Im supposed to prove a proposition and i wonder if my proof holds, i will start with a definition:

"Let $R$ be a commutative ring, a nonzero element $p$ of $R$ is said to be irreducible if the following to conditions hold:
$\textbf{(i)}$: $p$ is not a unit of $R$. $\textbf{(ii)}$: if $p=ab$ for $a,b, \in R$, then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit of $R$."

$\textbf{Proposition}$: Let $D$ be a principal ideal domain and let $p$ be a nonzero element of $D$. Then $p$ is irreducible in $D$ if and only if $pD$ is a prime ideal of $D$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: I have proven that if it is irreducible then it must be a prime ideal so lets take the other implication.

Assume that $pD$ is a prime ideal of $D$, then $p$ can not be a unit because if it was then we would have $pp^{-1}=1 \in pD$, contradicting the definition of a prime ideal as a proper ideal. Now suppose that $p$ is not irreducible, since $(i)$ holds (from above definition) then $(ii)$ can not hold, so if we can write $p =ab$ for $a,b \in D$ then both $a$ and $b$ must be nonunits, however we can write $p = 1*p$, this contradicts the definition of $1$ as an identity element and hence a unit. Thus $p$ is irreducible.

Does this proof hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is not valid; you made a mistake: for (ii) to be false, it means *there exist* $a, b$ nonunits such that $p = ab$, it *doesn't* mean that if $p = ab$ then both $a, b$ must be nonunits; obviously, as you noted $p = 1 \cdot p$ and $1$ is a unit!

Notice that in a PID, an element is prime if and only if it is irreducible. The result you want follows from the following:

**Lemma**: Let $A$ be a ring and $p \in A$, then $p$ is prime if and only if $(p)$ is prime.

**Proof**: Let $p$ be prime and let $xy \in (p)$, then $xy = pr$ for some $r \in A$ which means $p \mid xy$. Since $p$ is prime, either $p \mid x$, in which case $x = pr_x \in (p)$ for some $r_x \in A$ or $p \mid y$, in which case $y = pr_y \in (p)$ for some $r_y \in A$. Conclude that $(p)$ is prime by definition.

Conversely, suppose $(p)$ is prime and let $p \mid xy$, then $xy = pr$ for some $r \in A$ which means $xy \in (p)$. Since $(p)$ is prime, either $x \in (p)$ in which case $x = pr_x$ for some $r_x \in A$ which means $p \mid x$, or $y \in (p)$ in which case $y = pr_y$ for some $r_y \in A$ which means $p \mid x$. Conclude by definition that $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the last argument, which imo should be along the lines:

$$ab\in pD\implies a\in pD\;\;or\;\;b\in pD\implies\begin{cases}p\mid a\\{}\\or\\{}\\p\mid b\end{cases}$$

and we're done.

Comment: This is how the book proves the statement, it starts of by saying:

"If $p$ is not irreducible, then $p=ab$ for some non units $a$ and $b$ of $D$."

And then goes on like you did, however i dont understand why we even can write $p$ as $ab$ in the first place, IF we can do this, then of course $a$ and $b$ are non units but WHY can this be done?

Comment: Also, i would like to know if my proof is valid, please tell me what part is unclear i really want to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Besides being a proper ideal, a prime ideal also satisfies the following property (in its definition):

If $a, b \in D$ are such that $ab \in pD$, then $a \in pD$ or $b \in pD$.

I think you should use this in your proof somehow.